# Does the Magical Star Kanon 100% spinoff fit canonically within the main series?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

Kanon is featured in a manga and OVA anime spinoff titled *Magical Star Kanon 100%* in Shogakukan's Weekly Shonen Sunday magazine where she becomes a magical girl.

Is this series considered canon or another continuity (like *Neigma?! Neo*)?

If it is canon, where does it fit in the timeline of *The World God Only Knows*?

[image: マジカル☆スター かのん100%]

Answer (score 2):

It's just a spinoff because Kanon is extremely popular in Japan. You can't call it canon (or should I say, kanon), because it is not based off the material from the manga. However, Wakaki has drawn a few bonus chapters based off Magical Star Kanon, but does not hold the premise for the OVA's story.